# Subclassing ObjC and classes with C# in MonoTouch and MonoDroid

Tags: android, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm about to evaluate MonoTouch and MonoDroid to unify our development but I'm not sure if I got the subclassing of the two right. The documentation of both, MonoTouch and MonoDroid [http://ios.xamarin.com/Documentation/API_Design#Design_Principles](http://android.xamarin.com/Documentation/API_Design#Design_Principles) says you'd be able to create subclasses from ObjC and Java code.

Does that mean I can actually take existing none-framework code like a custom UI element or existing business logic and create a subclass of it in C# to use in my project? An example would be great, because I don't the slightest clue of how that works with mono and C#.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can! Here's an example of Miguel's [GlassButton](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Utilities/GlassButton.cs) of MonoTouch.

As you can see it inherits from the managed bindings of the native iOS [UIButton](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) and from there it can override its methods, just like you would expect in C#.

```
 public class GlassButton : UIButton {
    ...

    public override bool BeginTracking (UITouch uitouch, UIEvent uievent)
    {
       SetNeedsDisplay ();
       pressed = true;
       return base.BeginTracking (uitouch, uievent);
    }
    ...
```

You can do the same by binding your own UI (or not UI) code and then use it as normal C# code (and inherit, override... it).

Binding code for MonoTouch and Mono for Android is different, but once done, it's all the same (C# wise).

Comment: Hi poupou, thank you very much for your detailed answer. This seems to be much easier than I expected… or feared. Now we'll really have to write a test app. ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Does that mean I can actually take existing non-framework code like a custom UI element or existing business logic and create a subclass of it in C# to use in my project?

If I'm understanding you, Maybe. :-)

In MonoTouch, you can by [binding the Objective-C type to a C# type](http://ios.xamarin.com/Documentation/Binding_New_Objective-C_Types), then subclassing the bound C# type. This is extremely flexible, and allows for subclassing ~any Objective-C type from C#. (There is no need for binding e.g. UIKit types, as those are already bound within `monotouch.dll`.)

The equivalent in Mono for Android -- subclassing a "random" Java class in C# -- isn't currently possible. C# code can only subclass types and implement interfaces found within `Mono.Android.dll` (which binds the types found in `android.jar`). Work is underway to relax this restriction in a future release.

Comment: Hi jonp, thanks for your answer. Are you sure about the missing subclassing for Android? Because if I understand @poupou correctly, it should be possible: _"Binding code for MonoTouch and Mono for Android is different, but once done, it's all the same (C# wise)."_

Comment: @brejoc: How MonoTouch and Mono for Android do things is very different. :-) As of 1.2.0, it's not possible for C# code to subclass "unbound" Java types (anything outside of Mono.Android.dll), because there's no way to tell the `.java` generator "don't generate a wrapper for this type." This will be changing in the forthcoming 1.9 release.